# Sencha touch has no fadeOut function

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

With `ExtJs` I can use `Ext.get("xxx").fadeOut(...)` to fade out a `html` element, but with Sencha Touch, if I do the same thing `Ext.get("xxx").fadeOut(...)`, it tells me that `fadeOut` is `undefined`. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you are getting a ref to a component or dom element you can use something like this.

```
me.getMain.down('#myComponentItemId').hide('fadeOut');

me.getMain.down('#myComponentItemId').show('slideIn');

.hide()
.show()

.hide('fadeOut')
.show('fadeIn')

.show({
    type: 'slide',
    duration: 500,
    direction: 'left' 
})
```

Etc etc